# c function call using a function arguments

Tags: c, function

> void TraverseList(const List *l , void (*Visit)(ListEntry)) { // }

I confused about the above function call within the argument of a function,how it is working?

Comment: I suggest you find some books to read, or at least some tutorials about *function pointers*.

Comment: It is not a function call but an argument of type `void(*)(ListEntry)`

Comment: You can always check https://cdecl.org/ - `void (*Visit)(ListEntry)` ==> declare Visit as pointer to function (ListEntry) returning void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Visit` is a function pointer parameter passed to the `TraverseList` function. It should point to a function with the format

```
void func (ListEntry);
```

Likely, `TraverseList` will call the passed function for every item in the list.